# $\omega$ 1-form, if $d(f\omega)=0$ then $\omega\wedge d\omega=0$

Tags: proof-verification, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

> "Let $\omega$ be a 1-form on a smooth manifold $M$ and let $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function everywhere non-vanishing such that $d(f\omega)=0$. Prove that $\omega\wedge d\omega=0$".

My idea is:
$d(f\omega)=df\wedge \omega+fd\omega=0$ that means $fd\omega=\omega\wedge df$. Now we consider $$f\omega\wedge d\omega=\omega\wedge fd\omega=\omega\wedge\omega\wedge df=0$$ since $\omega\wedge\omega=0$. Now since $f$ is a non-vanishing function, must be $\omega\wedge d\omega=0$. Does it work?

Comment: To be more precise, you take $\omega\wedge d\omega$, and multiply it with the smooth function $1=\frac ff$ which doesn't change the form. Then your argument shows that the result is $0$. But yeah, it works.

Answer (score 1):

*From the comments above.*

---

Yes, this works.

To be more precise, take the form $\omega \wedge d\omega$ and multiply it with the smooth function $1 = \frac ff$. This can be done because $f$ is non-vanishing everywhere, and note that multiplying by $1$ does not change the form.

Now, your argument shows that $1 \omega \wedge d\omega = \frac 1f (f \omega \wedge d\omega) = \frac 1f 0 = 0.$ Hence, $\omega \wedge d\omega = 0$.